# Digikam: Is it possible to perform face detection/recognition on single photo?

Tags: face-detection, digikam

I go through my photo collection and place face tags manually. When I find picture without any detected face but with actual faces I want to add face tags to picture and to fill tag names.

Is it possible to force face detection and/or face recognition to just a single photo? Possibly with shortcut.

Comment: I'd guess this would be off-topic even if we knew what device/platform you were even talking about :/

Comment: @Tetsujin, I thought tag is enough. Thanks for noting. I added name of app to title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. DigiKam will do face recognition of a single photograph so long as you have other ones of the same face with tags to use for reference.

The KDE UserBase Wiki outlines the technique and procedure in several languages. You can find their relevant info here:[Digikam/Face Recognition](https://userbase.kde.org/Digikam/Face_Recognition)

Answer (score 0):

Picasa by google used to do this very well. after you have tagged a few people it then asks you to tag images where it cant recognise the people. it doesnt take long for it to be able to scan your entire directory and find everyone. you can then search for photos containing person a+b but not C for example.

I know this has been 'retired' as a program by google, and replaced. However for the face detection alone if this is something you need. Like finding every photo of a certain person, it may be worth downloading anyway.

Comment: You don't answer the question, it being "how to force face recognition to just a single photo"

Comment: Sorry maybe I was miss-understood. Face recognition, in terms of 'knowing' who it is can only possibly work when using an algorithm to compare to images it has been told are certain people. So a yes a single picture can be scanned, but only after it has learnt to recognise the people it contains. If you mean face detection, just know that there is a face there or not, then yes, most editing software has something of this nature. you camera itself probably does.